# How do I clone a html form in extjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

How do i clone html from extjs ?

like a

```
$('#copy').append($('#orig .elem')
.clone()
.children('a')
.prepend('foo - ')
.parent()
.clone());
```

I thought something like

```
//Component 1
var comp1 = new Ext.form.TextField({});


//Component cloning...
var comp2 = comp1.cloneConfig();
```

But I need to add a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExtJS is object oriented, so instead of "cloning" you can "extend" one component from another and override any methods or properties as needed.